# jquery mouseover visibility for multiple multiple image captions

Tags: jquery, image, visibility, captions

I'm trying to display photo captions on a gallery on `mouseover`, then on `mouseout` it hides the caption.

Here's the html:

```
<ul class="gallerylist">
    <li class="galleryitem">
        <a href="https://www.google.com"><img class="videothumb" src="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png"></a>
        <br />
        <div id="thumb-rollover">Rollover caption 1
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="galleryitem">
        <a href="https://www.google.com"><img class="videothumb" src="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png"></a>
        <br />
        <div id="thumb-rollover">Rollover caption 2
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="galleryitem">
        <a href="https://www.google.com"><img class="videothumb" src="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png"></a>
        <br />
        <div id="thumb-rollover">Rollover caption 3
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

id `thumbnail-roller` is hidden by default

I started with the following jquery but not sure if this is the right approach.. should I use `hover`?? Right now it only displays the caption for the first item instead of the one that I `mouseover`. Any help is appreciated.

```
$("li.galleryitem").mouseover(function() {
    $("#thumb-rollover").css('visibility', 'visible');
});
```

Here's the jsfiddle sample:
http://jsfiddle.net/gjxubcru/

Comment: `id`'s must be unique. u can use `class` instead. try this http://jsfiddle.net/gjxubcru/1/

Comment: Thanks, will try this!

Comment: let me know if it works for u.

Comment: did the fiddle work for you?

Comment: @Sushil it looks great on fiddle but when I tried to implement this morning, it is a bit jumpy so with my galleryitems (due to using the block attribute). I tried the next solution and this seems to work. Thanks for your help though.

Comment: you're most welcome :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hover() is for this situation. It takes two parameters, one for mouseenter and one for mouseleave. Here is an explanation : [hover and mouseover.](http://www.quora.com/jQuery/What-is-the-difference-between-the-hover-and-mouseover-functions) The reason the first one always shows is because ids need to be unique (your's aren't) and it's the first one with that id.

To fix the JSFiddle, the HTML and CSS id "thumb-roller" should be changed to a class. Then, give each of those divs an id like "thumb-roller-1", etc. Then change the JS to

```
$("li.galleryitem").hover(function() {
  //this is for mouseenter
  $("#thumb-rollover-" + this.id).css('visibility','visible');
}, function() {
  //this is for mouseleave
  $("#thumb-rollover-" + this.id).css('visibility','hidden');
});
```

here is a working JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/1ww0qafw/

Comment: This worked Sam. I had to make each id unique.. it is a bit more overhead in css because then I have to create #thumb-roller-1, #thumb-roller-2 etc.. but this is a fairly simple page and won't be updated often. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Glad it worked. To make the CSS shorter, each caption div can be given a class, such as `thumb-roller`, and then that can be styled `.thumb-roller{...}` in the same way you were styling the thumb roller id.